# JSF issue with default value in selectInputText

Tags: java, jsf, request

I am having a problem with default value in a search page. I am using JSF with IceFaces.

First, let me start with what I have.

I have a Search Page which searches with two input boxes Employee Name and Employee Number.

I have a List Page which List whatever I have searched. It has Edit and Redo button.

I have an Edit Page which lets me Edit and I can Save. It has Save and Redo button.

**Search Page**

Employee Name: ........

Employee Number: ........

||Search Button||

**List Page**

Employee Name

Employee Number

Employee Location

||Edit Button|| ||Redo||

**Edit Page**

Employee Name

Employee Number

Employee Location

||Save Button|| ||Redo||

**Scenario #1**

Lets say I am in the Search Page and enter a valid Employee Name and Employee Number. After I hit the Search button it goes to the List Page. After I am in List Page if I press Redo it directs me to Search Page but this time the Search Page automatically will have a default value of the search I recently performed.(instead of just empty Input Boxes)

**Scenario #2**

Lets say I am again in the Search Page and enter a valid Employee Name and Employee Number. After I hit the Search button it goes to the List Page. After I am in the List Page and press Edit then it directs me to the Edit Page. Once I am in Edit Page lets say I change the Employee Number of the Employee and hit Save (I am still on the List Page after the save) . Lets say I hit Redo button it again redirects me back to Search Page but without default value of the search of the search I recently performed (the Search Page will have empty Input Boxes)

The questions:

1) First of all, I have not been able to figure out how is JSF able to give the default values for the Search Page once I hit the redo(after an initial Search/Scenario #1). Is there a session variable/request variable built in.

2) Now for the second scenario it does not have the default value, I am not sure why it would not have one. So , basically I am trying to figure out where is this request variable in JSF which they are using to populate the Input Text Boxes.

Thanks for the help and support.

Comment: What scope have you defined for your backing bean? If you haven't defined one, the default scope of Request will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are you using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().redirect() to navigate between pages (not the history.back() or history.go(-1) ).

If your are doing this, any request or view variable should disappear if you move or press the refresh button in the navigator.

If you are using session variables (which means that you want to preserve it between pages) you need to clean it before the redirect or in the constructor method of the class, for example.

**XHTML / JSP**

> < h:inputText value="#{class.search}" />

**Java**

> public class Class{
>
> ```
>     //this variable need to have the getter and setter
>     private String search;
>     public Class (){
>            //build a method that clean all your variables;
>            SessionBean.clean();
>     }
> ```
>
> }

I hope it was useful. If not, give me more details of your implementation to help you.